# How can i update the rows of a Dataframe with to make them a dictionary with the column names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this.

```
ID  Name id2 name2
101  A    1   d_a
103  B    2   d_b
101  A    3   d_c
103  B    4   d_d
```

and i want the output df like this.

```
ID   Name id2                     name2
101  A    [{'id2':1},{'id2':3}]  [{'name2':'d_a'},{'name2':'d_c'}]
103  B    [{'id2':2},{'id2':4}]  [{'name2':'d_b'},{'name2':'d_d'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[df[[x]].to_dict('r') for x in df]], columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
                                      col1  \
0  [{'col1': 1}, {'col1': 2}, {'col1': 3}]   

                                                col2  
0  [{'col2': 'def'}, {'col2': 'bb'}, {'col2': 'ra'}]
```

EDIT: Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
cols = ['id2','name2']
df2 = df.groupby(['ID','Name'])[cols].agg(lambda x: x.to_frame().to_dict('r')).reset_index()
print (df2)
    ID Name                       id2                                 name2
0  101    A  [{'id2': 1}, {'id2': 3}]  [{'name2': 'd_a'}, {'name2': 'd_c'}]
1  103    B  [{'id2': 2}, {'id2': 4}]  [{'name2': 'd_b'}, {'name2': 'd_d'}]
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael thank you for your quick response, can you please tell me, what if i wanted this to apply on a specific column, i tried that but getting an error like df has 2 columns you have defined only one.

Comment: Hi thank you again, but this method removed all the other columns i want to keep the first column in the output as it is and modify as per the requiement. thanks in advance _/\_

Comment: @R.singh - Can you change sample data in question with this new requrement? Because not understand what need. thanks.

Comment: can you please check i have edited the question. Please

Comment: @R.singh - Thank you for data and expected output, so is possible create answer ;) Happy coding!